# How can a GitHub user view a history of changes to issue comments?

Tags: github

My team and I use checklists in GitHub issue comments, especially in the first comment of an issue. The first comment becomes a summary that evolves over time, but it makes me uncomfortable that I don't know how to see the history of earlier versions of a changed comment.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible, according to a GitHub representative, on 2015-11-11.

Comment: Do you have a link for this?